# How to keep a slow async function from blocking others?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, performance

I have a background function which parses a lot of data from an array of files. The time to consume a single file can be long, so my function can sometimes tie up the JS engine for 2-3 seconds.

```
for (let x = 0; x <= dataView.byteLength - 1; x++) strView += String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(x))
```

I don't really need this to run more quickly, it's a low priority background process. What I do need is for this function (which is an async function called via void and not await) to not block other functions for 2-3 seconds at a time during processing of a single file.

Is there a way to modify this for loop to effectively give the JS event loop permission to do other tasks in the middle of the above "for" loop? I tried awaiting a short promise every so often in the loop, but that doesn't seem to yield. Is can what I'm seeking to do (to prevent a background process from blocking higher priorities) really only be accomplished through something like a Web Worker for true multi-threading/tasking?

Comment: Awaiting a short promise should work, but what does your short promise code look like?

Comment: "*this function, which is an async function*" - is it actually doing anything asynchronous? If you are not using `await`, you shouldn't mark it as `async` - the code is just synchronous as usual.

Comment: Why not use `const strView = String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(dataView.buffer))` instead of that loop?

Comment: Awaiting a short promise doesn't work because you're literally waiting for it to resolve, during which time no other code is executed, naturally. Remember, JS is single-threaded.

Comment: Yes, the function is async in other places before and after this for loop.

Answer (score 1):

v2.0

```js
function sleep(fff) {
  return new Promise(rs => setTimeout(rs, fff));
}

async function slow(count, callback, threshold = 10000) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < count) {
    callback(i++);
    if (i % threshold === 0) {
      await sleep(1);
    }
  }
}

var strView = '';
slow(dataView.byteLength, x => strView += String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(x))).then(() => {
  console.log(strView);
});
```

Comment: That seems to help, thanks!